# make executes commands not specified in the makefile

Tags: makefile

Say I have the following makefile:

```
TARGETS = a b c

all: $(TARGETS)
    @echo Done.

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo Compiling $@...
    touch $@

%: %.o
    @echo Building $@...
    touch $@
```

I'd expect that this should have no problem running: the `all` rule would trigger the `%`, rule, which would trigger the `%.o` rule, generates the `a.o`, `b.o`, and `c.o` files, and then the `a`, `b`, and `c` files would finally be generated.

However, running `make` causes the following output:

```
ghb@Nemo:~/Downloads$ make
g++     a.cpp   -o a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [a] Error 1
```

Why is i trying to run `g++` all of the sudden? I have no rules for that. Also, running `make a.o` followed by `make a` works fine, but running `make a` causes the behavior as above.

What can I do to prevent `make` from trying to "come up" with what it believes are suitable commands for a target?

Answer (score 0):

The last rule seems to be ignored or misunderstood, so make falls back on its implicit rule for cpp files (see [Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)).
It may be worked around with this syntax:

```
TARGETS := a b c

all: $(TARGETS)
        @echo Done.

%.o: %.cpp
        @echo Compiling $@...
        touch $@

define make_target
$(1): $(1).o
        @echo Building $$@...
        touch $$@
endef
$(foreach tgt, $(TARGETS), $(eval $(call make_target, $(tgt))))
```

By the way, use `make all` instead of `make` or only the first target will be built.

Comment: That's cool! But could you please explain a little bit on what's going on in your solution, and why it works and not mine?

Comment: Actually I have no explanation for why the "%: %o" rule is ignored. However if you replace it with "%.exe: %o" (together with each target name) it works! My solution defines a generic rule for each target (with define..endef), and the $(foreach..,$(eval..)) macro expands it for each element of TARGETS (see a description at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function).

Comment: ... and to answer your initial question, since the "%: %.o" rule is ignored, make falls back on its C++ implicit compilation rule (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), that's where the surprising g++ invokation comes from.

Answer (score 0):

There are three rules involved here, two that you wrote:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    @echo Compiling $@...
    touch $@

%: %.o
    @echo Building $@...
    touch $@
```

and one that is "built in":

```
%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@     # There's a little more to it, but never mind.
```

When you try to build `a`, Make goes through its list of rules and comes up with two candidates:

```
%: %.o    # yours
%: %.cpp  # built in
```

If `a.o` already exists, then your rule takes precedence (which is why your chain works if you `make a.o` first). If not, then Make chooses the second because `a.cpp` *does* exist.

If you don't want Make to consider these built-in rules when building your targets, use `make -r`, also known as `make --no-builtin-rules.`